# Scrollbar vertical em DIV em ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho um formulário dentro do content2 da masterpage. É possível metê-lo dentro de uma div com um scrollbar na vertical que desça unicamente o formulario em questão? Qual a forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Fala Bruno, blz?

Cara, acho que essa é uma forma simples de resolver seu problema:

```css
.div1 {
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
}

.div2 {
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.div3 {
  height:1500px;
  border:5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="div1">
    <div id="div2" class="div2">
        <div id="div3" class="div3">Conteúdo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```